# POST/GET requests in Angular-sails

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sails.js

I'm using [angular-sails](https://github.com/kyjan/angular-sails) in my project and I have a problem in sending POST or GET requests from angular controller. Here is my controller:

**Angular: UserController.js**

```
myApp.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, $sails) {
    $sails.post('/addUser', {name: 'test'}, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

While in sails server-side controller I have:

**Sails: UserController.js**

```
module.exports = {
    addUser: function(req, res) {
        //SQL query
        return res.json({success: true});
  },
  _config: {}
};
```

and in my route:

**Sails: routes.js**

```
module.exports.routes = {
    'post /addUser': {
        controller: 'UserController',
        action: 'addUser'
    }
}
```

Accessing the url: `localhost:1337/addUser` directly gives me:

```
{success: true}
```

However, issuing the post/get request from angular controller do nothing.

What might be the problem?

--

***Solution: Updating angular-sails to version v0.1.3 will solve the problem.***

Comment: Are you including `socket.io` and `sails.io` in your solution?

Comment: Yes I do. could it be a routing problem?

Comment: Further discussion: https://github.com/kyjan/angular-sails/issues/9

Answer will be posted here!

Comment: Updating angular-sails to version v0.1.3 will solve the problem.

Comment: You can post this as an answer and accept it yourself; that way it won't continue to show up as an Unanswered Question.

Comment: Have you tried angular-sails-bind? (https://github.com/diegopamio/angular-sails-bind) I bet you haven't, as I've just released to the world yesterday :). I made it for my own project and then decided to put it as a separated library so everybody could benefit and I could have my first experience developing a bower package.

I hope it could help you.

BTW: it works with sails 0.10 (as some things, like topic names had changed since 0.9). If you need to make it work with 0.9, just let me know and I'll happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating angular-sails to version v0.1.3 will solve the problem